# Checkstyle module/property to control the alignment of the Javadoc at-clauses

Tags: javadoc, checkstyle

Is there any Checkstyle module/property to control the alignment of the Javadoc at-clauses? I would like to check the existing at-clauses which are aligned to the same column, to fix them to be left-aligned

Current formatting:

```
/**
 * Some method.
 *
 * @param abcd some param
 * @param e    some param
 */
```

Desired formatting:

```
/**
 * Some method.
 *
 * @param abcd some param
 * @param e some param
 */
```

Comment: Any luck with this a year later?

Comment: Unfortunately no.